# What kind of Life Fitness machines are the biceps curl and triceps extension machines at Planet Fitness?

Tags: machine

What kind of Life Fitness machines are the biceps curl and triceps extension machines at Planet Fitness?  I’m talking about the ones that are not in the 30 minute express section, but are with the normal machines, but these particular machines have both arms working one bar, instead of each arm working its individual weight.

Comment: Do you happen to have a picture of one of them? They probably shop these machines from a single vendor.

Comment: Why don't you ask a staff member? They should probably know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact the “Pro2”.  Found it by checking the model name on the machine.

Comment: You can accept your own answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons.

Comment: I know, it won’t let me.

Comment: Ah, sorry, should have clarified. Accepting someone else's answer can be done in a few minutes after asking. Self-answers take 48 hours before you can do it. :) Please stick around?